# What is the << operator doing in C++?

Tags: c++, iostream, bit-shift

In the example below, what exactally is the `<<` operator doing? I'm guessing it is not a bitwise operator.

```
std::cout << "Mouse down @ " << event.getPos() << std::endl;
```

*I understand what the code will do here: Use standard out, send this text, send an end of line. Just I've never come accross the use of this << apart from on raw binary.*

I'm starting out with C++. And, as an operator of sorts, it's hard to search for a description of this and what it means. Can someone enlighten me and/or give me a pointer as to what to google for?

Thanks
Ross

Comment: You're wrong, because it won't replace the @.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The answer is: The `<<` operator does left shifts by default for integral types, but it can be overloaded to do whatever you want it to!

This syntax for piping strings into a stream was first (I think) demonstrated in C++ inventor Bjarne Stroustroup's eponymous book [The C++ Programming Language](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201700735). Personally, I feel that redefining an operator to do IO is gimmicky; it makes for cool-looking demo code but doesn't contribute to making code understandable. Operator overloading as a technique has been widely criticized in the programming language community.

---

**EDIT:** Since nobody else has mentioned this yet:

`operator<<` is defined in the `ostream` class, of which `cout` is an instance. The class definition sits in the [iostream library](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ostream/), which is `#include`'d as `<iostream>`.

Comment: I think it's a great tool to say exactly what you want in your code, and very useful when using stringstreams and fstreams for piping data into something

Comment: Actually, if you want to be pedantic, `operator<<` is a free function with an `ostream` as it's first argument.

Comment: @Billy ONeal: Surely you're more of an expert than I am, but isn't it an instance method of the `ostream` class, with (whatever's to the right) as its first argument?

Comment: I don't think operator overloading should be used at all because class methods can achieve the same functionality. In the case of `ostream`, the `operator<<` functionality can be achieved by having a method such as `write_formatted` that is chainable.

Comment: @Exception: Thank you for your opinion. Unfortunately what you're looking for breaks down when someone tries to do something like `myOstream << myClass`. Someone can add `operator<<` s just by adding an additional method; however one cannot just stick methods onto standard library classes.

Comment: @Carl: Actually, we're both right -- several of the operator<<s on primitive types are member functions. However the overloads for `const char *` are free functions. Also, any user defined class that is shifted out will be written in terms of a free function.

Comment: @Exception: I also don't think that the stream insertion operator should have an overloaded meaning for integral types, when the same functionality can be achieved by adding a library function `lshift`.

Comment: "Operator overloading as a technique has been widely criticized in the programming language community". Although the biggest direct criticism I've seen of operator overloading in C++ came with the design of Java, which itself (hypocritically, C++ fans could argue) uses operator overloading, for example in String addition. It just doesn't allow mere programmers to overload operators - that right is reserved to Language Designers ;-) (In reality, the biggest direct criticism of C++ operator overloading might be the average programmer's use of it...)

Answer (score 3):

The `operator<<` is being overloaded. Check out [Operator Overloading](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C++_Programming/Operators/Operator_Overloading#Overloadable_operators).

Answer (score 3):

This is sometimes called the 'stream insertion operator', and this is the most common use: to insert data into a stream.  Sometimes, however, I've seen it overloaded to insert data into other objects when doing things like serialization, for example.

Answer (score 3):

Like any operators in c++, << is doing operations.
Using overloading, with an ostream left operand (std::cout is of ostream type), it's used as a stream operator to print data of various types.
For example, you can do

```
int x = 10;
std::string y = " something";
std::cout << x << y << std::endl;
```

This will output "10 something".

@ is not replaced by anything in this context. operator<< just dump the result.

std::endl is not only the end of line, it also flushes the result to the output device.

Answer (score 1):

Try writing a program where you create an object and call the overloaded << operator,

```
class x {
    //declare some pvt variables
    //overload << operator
};

int main() {
    x obj;
    cout << obj;
}
```

By doing so you will understand the rationale behind using the following statement

```
cout << string_var << int_var;
```

You can assume 'string' and 'int' as classes that have overloaded << operator even though not true.

Answer (score -4):

It is a "**bitwise left shift**" operator.

> **n << p**

*Shifts the bits of n left p  positions. Zero bits are shifted into the low-order positions. 3 << 2 is 12.*

**In the context of the question it pushes something into '*cout*' which is the current output stream.**

Comment: @Nick Brooks: I've edited your last line to make it a bit clearer, but it's probably too late to save your answer from the hate it's getting.